# How to persuade VS Code to refer to the latest version of a package?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-code, nuget, package, dotnet-restore

We're using a private NuGet feed to manage a couple of dependencies.

After updating a dependency (e.g. adding a property to a class) and triggering build and release, I can see that `dotnet restore` downloads the new version:

```
$ dotnet restore
  Restoring packages for C:\Users\me\blah\whatever.csproj...
  Installing My.Package 1.0.NewVersion.
  Restore completed in 63.97 ms for C:\Users\me\blah\whatever.csproj.
  Generating MSBuild file C:\Users\me\blah\whatever.csproj.nuget.g.props.
```

But when I try to access the new property I get red squiggles. When I F12 to view the metadata of the class in question, sure enough, my property is absent.

If I nuke the NuGet cache and restore again, I'm able to get the new version. This feels like a nuclear option - is there a subtler way?

---

*Quick update...* The reference to the package in the csproj file looks like this:

```
<PackageReference Include="My.Package" Version="0.0.*" />
```

With the intention that it'll always refer to the latest patch version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I've found to do this reliably is a bit of a sledgehammer...

Step 1: Nuke nuget with `dotnet nuget locals all -clear`

Step 2: Restart Omnisharp using the command palette.

Comment: Just in case it helps someone: `--clear` (two dashes) or `-c` (one dash)